# How to resolve: "proj4_c_impl.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000440"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rgeo, proj

```
MacBook-Pro:sims moboyle$ rails s
/Users/moboyle/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rgeo-0.3.20/lib/rgeo/coord_sys/proj4_c_impl.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000440
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]
```

Any ideas?

Full stack dump @ https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo/issues/105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With assistance from @teeparham the following steps got things working for me:

- running `gem pristine rgeo`
- updating rails project to use ruby 2.2.3